# Laravel 5, The requested URL /myfirstproject/ was not found on this server

Tags: laravel-5, wampserver

I have successfully install the laravel 5 using Wamp server & successfully created first project with name "myfirstproject".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BmPp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK1x6.png)
Problem is that when i try to access "myfirstproject" through "localhost/myfirstproject"

it says

"Not Found

The requested URL /myfirstproject/ was not found on this server.
 Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16 Server at localhost Port 80"

And in localhost "myfirstproject" is in the list of My Projects.

Answer (score 0):

okey so laravel has nothing to do with wampserver you are just using php, you have to open your cmd then then cd /the directory of your project,Then Type php artisan serve ,if everything ok the server will start .

access your project this way 
localhost:8000/

if everything ok you should get a Laravel page

Answer (score 0):

you should write command line at your project directory
`php artisan serve`